# Checkbox POST true/false isntead of checked/NULL

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I try to make a small website, wehre you can create a table and out of this table, there will be a database generated. I have two inputfields for type/name and a **checkbox** for **NotNULL**.

Now my problem is, that if the client (browser) requests to change the **COLUMN COUNT**, I want to "store" the changes before and just add/remove the cells, and for that I want to send ture/false instead of checked/NULL. With that i can store them into the notNull Array (controller code)

This is how my Website looks like:

I also want the right button [0] to display "+" instead of its value, is that even possible with `<input>` fields?
[image]

### Code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
          <tr>
              <td id="td_id">
                  <input list="types" class="form-control" name="typeSelected" value="@Model.Columns[i].DbType">
                  <datalist id="types">
                      @foreach (var item in @Model.Columns[i].Types)
                      {
                          <option value="@item">@item</option>
                      }
                  </datalist>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" value="@Model.Columns[i].Name" />
              </td>
              <td>
                  @*@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Columns[i].notNull, new { @name="notNull" })*@
                  <input type="checkbox" name="notNull" class="checkbox" checked="@Model.Columns[i].notNull" value="true" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="notNull" class="checkbox" checked="@Model.Columns[i].notNull" value="false" />
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="addCell" value="@i" />
              </td>
          </tr>
      }
```

#### Controller:

```
private CreateTableModels model = new CreateTableModels();
//
// GET: /CreateTable/
public ActionResult Index(int count = 1, System.Data.SqlDbType[] typeSelected = null, string[] Name = null, bool[] notNull = null, string[] addCell = null)
{
    if (count < 0)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    while (count > model.Columns.Count)
    {
        model.Columns.Add(new QlikViewStammdaten.Models.CreateTableColumnModels());
    }
    while (count < model.Columns.Count)
    {
        model.Columns.RemoveAt(model.Columns.Count - 1);
    }

    SetOldValues(typeSelected, "DbType");
    SetOldValues(Name, "Name");
    SetOldValues(notNull, "notNull");

    return View(model);
}

private void SetOldValues<T>(T[] type, string name) 
{
    if (type != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < type.Count(); i++)
        {
            var obj = model.Columns[i];
            var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name);
            if (prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
            {
                prop.SetValue(obj, type[i], null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Controller Code please

Comment: What are doing with that much array ? what you want to achieve?

Comment: I added it above @CoolJK

Comment: If you change the amount of columns, all the existing changes to the input fields would be lost, so i post it to the server and somehow store them @CoolJK

Comment: You can use jquery for that to stop post the form using some condition.

Comment: What you want to achieve using this code?

Comment: Read above, I added something @CoolJK

Comment: It's difficult to understand what is being asked. For me the confusion starts with "if the client requests to change the column size". What client? Browser? Why does it request to change the column size? Are you resizing the window, so columns size get changed? What columns are these? It does not look like database columns, since on your screenshot there does not seem to have a field for database column size - just the type and the name. Very unclear. And after that quoted part everything else does not parse because the beginning is not clear.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSavinykh i made some changes to my question, is there something you still don't understand/ is still not clear?

Comment: It's not about the size of the column its about the count, the table should have